# How can I import/run an android project to eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to import an example project into eclipse. I downloaded the file `SlidingTabsColors.zip` from [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html), unpacked it, and then choose

```
Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace -> Browse -> ...
```

and selected the project named 'MainActivity'.

When I try to run this application the Console gives an error:

```
Could not find MainActivity.apk!
```

I thought the purpose of eclipse is to create the `apk` file...

Anyway, do I need to do some additional steps in order to run this example?

Comment: This projects is using Gradle, the easiest way to compile is to use Android Studio or make a new project from the source/xml.

Comment: I have no idea what 'gradle' means. And I just installed eclipse which took a very long time. So the suggestion is to install even more stuff, trashing the harddisk?

Comment: Gradle is a build system, to automate some build process... But the thing is, you downloaded a project made for Gradle and an IDE with the default build system... Seems like Google is updating all its docs and samples to the new improved IDE Android Studio.

Comment: Is there some overview what developing tool (eclipse, andoid studio, kdevelop, emacs, vi, ...) I can use for what project (android java, android C++, ...) with all the different build systems (gradle, maven, ...) and how then even things such as unity and other engines blend in? I am completly confused by all these different 'things' and I have no idea how they fit together, it at all...

Comment: Eclipse is the classic IDE. Android studio (and Gradle) are new. vi is linux based. 95% of the source code you'll find for android will work very happily with eclipse.

Comment: You can use almost any combination you prefer... but the sample you downloaded was prepared in Android Studio, which is for default using Gradle and Java.

Comment: Can you suggest a different place with example code without gradle, which I am able to import to eclipse without this gradle issue?

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer with a link. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
New -> Other -> Android Project From Existing Code
```

This should work no problem. Android does create the APK upon a successful compile. If you run into any issues, just do:

```
Project -> Clean
```

[**Here**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) is a step-by-step tutorial on Tab Layouts with Swipeable Views. Which is what I believe you're trying to achieve.

**Download Link:** **[Source Code](https://www.mediafire.com/?rayb4y349wajf47)**

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Let me download it and try myself. One sec.

Comment: @Alex You're better off just either implementing it yourself, or finding a non-gradle project. I've updated my answer with a link you may be interested in. :)

Comment: @Alex I've included the download link to the eclipse project. It does the same thing as your project, so you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a **New folder** in your computer.
2. put the **java** and **res** files in that new folder
3. just rename the folder from **java** into **src**
4. copy the AndroidManifest.xml into the root folder
5. now try to import this from eclipse

Comment: i edited the answer now.Copy AndroidManifest.xml into the root folder

Comment: Does not work either. The code line 'import android.os.Bundle;' gives an error. Do I need to install some extra packages?

Comment: is it successfully imported now??

Comment: create a folder named libs and add android-support-v4.jar into it.It may help.